# Google App Engine: com.google.appengine.api.labs.modules.ModulesException: No valid instance id for this instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I recently upgraded my app engine SDK from 1.7.7.1 to 1.8.5 and my endpoint API's stopped working. My API explorer wont even load. After turning up my log level I discovered the error below when I attempt to access the API explorer. I've been having some trouble with my workspace and google app engine so I decided to set up a fresh install of eclipse(eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64) with a fresh copy of the latest app engine SDK(1.8.5) which I installed through the marketplace. I created a basic entity called Book and generated an endpoint called BookEndpoint(see below for code) and the error still occurs.

Any Ideas?

```
FINE: started Server@4c469ca0
Oct 08, 2013 5:29:20 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger debug
FINE: File added: C:\Users\Daniel\workspace\wspace_rebuild\testgce\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
Oct 08, 2013 5:29:20 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http:// localhost:8888/
Oct 08, 2013 5:29:20 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http:// localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Oct 08, 2013 1:29:20 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Oct 08, 2013 1:29:47 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter getCurrentModuleInstance
FINE: Exception getting module instance
com.google.appengine.api.labs.modules.ModulesException: No valid instance id for this instance.
    at com.google.appengine.api.labs.modules.ModulesServiceImpl.getCurrentInstanceId(ModulesServiceImpl.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.getCurrentModuleInstance(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:210)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.isLoadBalancingRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:186)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.getRequestType(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:175)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)







package com.dan;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

@Entity
public class Book {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    private String name;

public Key getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(Key key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}










package com.dan;

import com.dan.EMF;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor;
import com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPACursorHelper;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityExistsException;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Api(name = "bookendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "dan.com", ownerName = "dan.com", packagePath = ""))
public class BookEndpoint {

    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
     * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
     *
     * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
     * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    @ApiMethod(name = "listBook")
    public CollectionResponse<Book> listBook(
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        EntityManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<Book> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Book as Book");
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
            }

            if (limit != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(0);
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
            }

            execute = (List<Book>) query.getResultList();
            cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (Book obj : execute);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }

        return CollectionResponse.<Book> builder().setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
    }

    /**
     * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
     * @return The entity with primary key id.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getBook")
    public Book getBook(@Named("id") Long id) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        Book book = null;
        try {
            book = mgr.find(Book.class, id);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return book;
    }

    /**
     * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
     * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP POST method.
     *
     * @param book the entity to be inserted.
     * @return The inserted entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "insertBook")
    public Book insertBook(Book book) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {
            if (containsBook(book)) {
                throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
            }
            mgr.persist(book);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return book;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used for updating an existing entity. If the entity does not
     * exist in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP PUT method.
     *
     * @param book the entity to be updated.
     * @return The updated entity.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "updateBook")
    public Book updateBook(Book book) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {
            if (!containsBook(book)) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
            }
            mgr.persist(book);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return book;
    }

    /**
     * This method removes the entity with primary key id.
     * It uses HTTP DELETE method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the entity to be deleted.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "removeBook")
    public void removeBook(@Named("id") Long id) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {
            Book book = mgr.find(Book.class, id);
            mgr.remove(book);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
    }

    private boolean containsBook(Book book) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        boolean contains = true;
        try {
            Book item = mgr.find(Book.class, book.getKey());
            if (item == null) {
                contains = false;
            }
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return contains;
    }

    private static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    }

}


{
  "extends" : "thirdParty.api",
  "abstract" : false,
  "root" : "https://appname.appspot.com/_ah/api",
  "name" : "bookendpoint",
  "version" : "v1",
  "defaultVersion" : false,
  "adapter" : {
    "bns" : "https://appname.appspot.com/_ah/spi",
    "deadline" : 10.0,
    "type" : "lily"
  },
  "auth" : {
    "allowCookieAuth" : false
  },
  "frontendLimits" : {
    "unregisteredUserQps" : -1,
    "unregisteredQps" : -1,
    "unregisteredDaily" : -1,
    "rules" : [ ]
  },
  "cacheControl" : {
    "type" : "no-cache",
    "maxAge" : 0
  },
  "ownerDomain" : "dan.com",
  "ownerName" : "dan.com",
  "methods" : {
    "bookendpoint.removeBook" : {
      "path" : "book/{id}",
      "httpMethod" : "DELETE",
      "authLevel" : "NONE",
      "scopes" : [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" ],
      "audiences" : [ ],
      "clientIds" : [ "292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com" ],
      "rosyMethod" : "com.dan.BookEndpoint.removeBook",
      "request" : {
        "parameters" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "int64",
            "required" : true
          }
        },
        "body" : "empty"
      },
      "response" : {
        "body" : "empty"
      }
    },
    "bookendpoint.insertBook" : {
      "path" : "book",
      "httpMethod" : "POST",
      "authLevel" : "NONE",
      "scopes" : [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" ],
      "audiences" : [ ],
      "clientIds" : [ "292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com" ],
      "rosyMethod" : "com.dan.BookEndpoint.insertBook",
      "request" : {
        "body" : "autoTemplate(backendRequest)",
        "bodyName" : "resource"
      },
      "response" : {
        "body" : "autoTemplate(backendResponse)"
      }
    },
    "bookendpoint.getBook" : {
      "path" : "book/{id}",
      "httpMethod" : "GET",
      "authLevel" : "NONE",
      "scopes" : [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" ],
      "audiences" : [ ],
      "clientIds" : [ "292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com" ],
      "rosyMethod" : "com.dan.BookEndpoint.getBook",
      "request" : {
        "parameters" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "int64",
            "required" : true
          }
        },
        "body" : "empty"
      },
      "response" : {
        "body" : "autoTemplate(backendResponse)"
      }
    },
    "bookendpoint.updateBook" : {
      "path" : "book",
      "httpMethod" : "PUT",
      "authLevel" : "NONE",
      "scopes" : [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" ],
      "audiences" : [ ],
      "clientIds" : [ "292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com" ],
      "rosyMethod" : "com.dan.BookEndpoint.updateBook",
      "request" : {
        "body" : "autoTemplate(backendRequest)",
        "bodyName" : "resource"
      },
      "response" : {
        "body" : "autoTemplate(backendResponse)"
      }
    },
    "bookendpoint.listBook" : {
      "path" : "book",
      "httpMethod" : "GET",
      "authLevel" : "NONE",
      "scopes" : [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" ],
      "audiences" : [ ],
      "clientIds" : [ "292824132082.apps.googleusercontent.com" ],
      "rosyMethod" : "com.dan.BookEndpoint.listBook",
      "request" : {
        "parameters" : {
          "cursor" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "required" : false
          },
          "limit" : {
            "type" : "int32",
            "required" : false
          }
        },
        "body" : "empty"
      },
      "response" : {
        "body" : "autoTemplate(backendResponse)"
      }
    }
  },
  "descriptor" : {
    "schemas" : {
      "Book" : {
        "id" : "Book",
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "key" : {
            "$ref" : "Key"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "Key" : {
        "id" : "Key",
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "kind" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "appId" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "format" : "int64"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "parent" : {
            "$ref" : "Key"
          },
          "complete" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "namespace" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "CollectionResponse_Book" : {
        "id" : "CollectionResponse_Book",
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "items" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "$ref" : "Book"
            }
          },
          "nextPageToken" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "methods" : {
      "com.dan.BookEndpoint.removeBook" : {
      },
      "com.dan.BookEndpoint.insertBook" : {
        "request" : {
          "$ref" : "Book"
        },
        "response" : {
          "$ref" : "Book"
        }
      },
      "com.dan.BookEndpoint.getBook" : {
        "response" : {
          "$ref" : "Book"
        }
      },
      "com.dan.BookEndpoint.updateBook" : {
        "request" : {
          "$ref" : "Book"
        },
        "response" : {
          "$ref" : "Book"
        }
      },
      "com.dan.BookEndpoint.listBook" : {
        "response" : {
          "$ref" : "CollectionResponse_Book"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ModulesException is a known issue on the dev server:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10412

It wouldn't be related to endpoints problems.